# unable to install npm on the AWS RHEL7 AMI because of c-ares-devel dependency

Tags: rhel7, npm

I've added the EPEL repository and attempted to install npm (since it is not included in the standard repos), but get the following error:

```
Error: Package: nodejs-devel-0.10.33-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: c-ares-devel(x86-64)
```

`No package c-ares-devel available.` when I try to install that.

Adding RPMForge repo does not help.

`yum --skip-broken install npm` just skips the npm package.

The `c-ares` package is installed but does not seem to meet the `c-ares-devel` dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The c-ares-devel package is in the RHEL optional channel. You need to make sure you enable this channel.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run:

```
# yum clean all
# yum update c-ares
# yum install c-ares-devel
```

before trying to install npm?

Also, if you're still getting errors, just download CentOS packages for c-ares and thats it:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://centos.eecs.wsu.edu/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/Packages/c-ares-1.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
# rpm -Uvh http://centos.eecs.wsu.edu/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/Packages/c-ares-devel-1.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
# yum install npm
```

Hope it helps.